# how can i use share preference in counter in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, counter

Excuse me because 3 of my simple question, but I need your help. I want to have a counter (with using `shared preference`) in my app like this:

- At the first, there are 2 buttons, `START` and `RESET`. If `RESET` is
  clicked, the counter starts from `0`.
  Also if `START` is clicked, the counter starts from shared preference data.
- Start counting
- At last time, I want to save counter in share preference. (but I don't know its better to save it in BACK btn or CLICK btn)

My problem is in share preference part. Please help me how can I do this? Thanks a lot!

---

Edit: this is my code

```
public class CountActivity extends Activity {
private Button click;
private int count,savedCount;
private String count_text;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.counting);

    click= (Button) findViewById(R.id.vow_counting);
    final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Far_Homa.ttf");

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("counters", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();

    AlertDialog.Builder fBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(VowCountActivity.this);

    fBuilder.setMessage("please choose");
    fBuilder.setCancelable(false);

    fBuilder.setPositiveButton("start from beging", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            count = sharedPreferences.getInt("counter", 0);

            click.setText("0");
            click.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Far_Homa.ttf"));
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });

    fBuilder.setNegativeButton("countinue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            count = sharedPreferences.getInt("counter",savedCount);

            editor.putInt("counter",savedCount).commit();
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });

    fBuilder.show();



    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           count++;
           count_text=Integer.toString(count);
           click.setText(count_text);
           click.setTypeface(typeface);
           savedCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("savedCounter", count);
           vibrate(500);
        }
    });
}


// vibrate
public void vibrate(int duration)  {
    Vibrator vibs = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibs.vibrate(duration);
}
```

Comment: can you show me as a example what you have done...I up-voted... Lot of people will down-vote if you don't show what you have done.....

Comment: thanks a lot for all helps. I read all answers and do something like below.now I have 2 questions:

Comment: 1- how can I save "count" in SP and continue it in COUNTINUE btn?

Comment: 2- the VIBRATE method doesn't work correctly?("the app has been stoped is shown"). why?

Answer (score 1):

To get value on start button you can define this function and have value for shared preferences

```
public static int getIntPreferences(String key) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_FILE_NAME, 0);
    return settings.getInt(key, 0);
}
```

Now to reset your shared preferences value you can use the following function

```
public static void updatePreferences(String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PROFILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
        edit.putString("yourPreferenceName", yourPreferenceObject);
        edit.commit();
```

for saving preference

and

```
       SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("PROFILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       String string = preferences.getString("yourPreferenceName", "defaultReturn");
```

for receiving your sharedPreferences
.get and .put with return type

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("counterStat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();

             btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                int counter = preferences.getInt("counter", 0);
             // counter = counter + 1;  start counting  
                edit.putInt("counter", counter).commit();
               }
             });

            btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {   
              edit.putInt("counter", 0).commit();
             }
            });
```

**Dialog back:**

```
  int counter = preferences.getInt("counter", 0);
  edit.putInt("savedCounter", counter).commit();
```

**Dialog cancel:**

```
 int counter = preferences.getInt("counter", 0);
 edit.putInt("savedCounter", counter).commit();
 edit.putInt("counter", 0).commit();
```

Then you can use: int savedCounter = preferences.getInt("savedCounter", 0); anywhere

Answer (score 0):

> Here is how to add an entry to SharedPrefs, and save to disk.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("name", "Adam");
editor.commit();
```

> Here is how to read a saved value from SharedPrefs.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", 0);
String name = settings.getString("name", null);
```